# Adding an action listener to JButtons created by a loop

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am having trouble finding a way to invoke an action listener that returns the value of the button clicked in the text area at the bottom.

I made the buttons using a for loop and did not expressly give the buttons a name so I do not know how to reference them when trying to incorporate an `ActionListener`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class buttoner implements ActionListener {
//JFrame
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Game");

//Make JPanels
JPanel panelLabel = new JPanel();
JPanel buttonGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,10));
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

//JLabel
private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("The Button Game");

public buttoner() {
    //set layout
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panelLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(buttonGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //Set stuff
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //Change label color
    label1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    //add Label
    panelLabel.add(label1);
    //add Buttons
    for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
        String val = Integer.toString(i);
        buttonGrid.add(new JButton(val));
    }
    //Add JText Area to bottom JPanel
    String num = "value";
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(num, 1, 1);
    bottomPanel.add(jta);
    frame.pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    buttoner gui = new buttoner();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an action listener to put the value in the text area at the bottom of the GUI.

[image: The Button Game]

I fixed a few problems with your code.

1. In the main method, I called the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to put the Swing GUI on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT).  Swing components must be created and updated on the EDT.
2. The name of a Java class must start with a capital letter.
3. It's safer to put your Swing components on a JPanel, rather than add them directly to a JFrame.
4. I separated the code that creates the JFrame from the code that creates the JPanels.  It should be easier for any reader of your code, including yourself, to understand what's going on.
5. In the createMainPanel method, I grouped the code so that everything having to do with the buttonGrid JPanel, to take one instance, is in one place in the code.
6. I added the action listener to the code that creates the buttonGrid JPanel.
7. I wrote action listener code that updates the JTextArea with the left clicked button label.

Here's the corrected code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Buttoner implements ActionListener {
    // JFrame
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Game");

    // Make JPanels
    private JPanel panelLabel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 10));
    private JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

    // JLabel
    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("The Button Game");

    private JTextArea jta;

    public Buttoner() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Change label color
        label1.setForeground(Color.RED);
        // add Label
        panelLabel.add(label1);
        panel.add(panelLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // add Buttons
        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
            String val = Integer.toString(i);
            JButton button = new JButton(val);
            button.addActionListener(this);
            buttonGrid.add(button);
        }
        panel.add(buttonGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add JText Area to bottom JPanel
        String num = "value";
        jta = new JTextArea(num, 1, 1);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        bottomPanel.add(jta);
        panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Buttoner();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        JButton button = (JButton) a.getSource();
        jta.setText(button.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the first thing I have done in Java but I have one question. What does this do?

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Buttoner();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);

Comment: @Jon Stinnett: As I said in the answer, the Runnable code and the SwingUtilities invokeLater code put the creation and updating of the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an array of buttons and add the newly created button to the array. See comments.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class buttoner implements ActionListener {
//JFrame
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Game");

//Make JPanels
JPanel panelLabel = new JPanel();
JPanel buttonGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,10));
JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();

//JLabel
private JLabel label1 = new JLabel("The Button Game");
private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[60]; //create an array of button for future reference

public buttoner() {
    //set layout
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panelLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(buttonGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //Set stuff
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //Change label color
    label1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    //add Label
    panelLabel.add(label1);
    //add Buttons
    for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
        String val = Integer.toString(i);
        JButton btn = new JButton(val);
        btn.addActionListener(this); //add an actionListener right away
        buttons[i] = btn; //add the button in the array for future reference
        buttonGrid.add(btn);
    }
    //Add JText Area to bottom JPanel
    String num = "value";
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(num, 1, 1);
    bottomPanel.add(jta);
    frame.pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    buttoner gui = new buttoner();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {

}
}
```